# 6 1/2 year old sleeping with hands on his wee

Tags: primary-schooler, age-appropriate

I posted this question [about the Toddler keeping his hands in the private part](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/39123/does-toddler-keep-hands-around-private-parts). Tonight I found him in bed sleeping while his hands were on his private part. I had to see if he was just keeping under Pj's but he was covering his welly with it.

Should I be concerned? How can I know if he is watching something (he do watch a lot of tv cartoon) or why he is doing that. I am just baffled to see it. God forbid if he get onto wrong habits it never goes away.

Comment: One of my kids held on to his as though he was sure it would fall off if he let go. In public, in private, all the time. This, too, shall pass.

Comment: @anongoodnurse How do I talk to him. I never seen behaviour like this from him also the thing that scares me I was molested as a kid n since then until few years ago I left a very bad habit so I guess my fear is more stronger .

Answer (score 7):

This isn't unusual or anything to be worried about.  Since he was already asleep it's quite likely his hands ended up where they did randomly as he tossed and turned.  Even if it was intentional there could be many reasons for it and all of them are harmless.  It's not interfering with his sleep, it's not physically hurting him, it won't make his penis fall off.  Really it's not a big deal.

If your concern is that he is masturbating I don't think this description alone proves that, but frankly it wouldn't matter if he was.   Masturbation does happen in kids that age often enough.  It's well known and documented.  It's also known that it doesn't harm a child, at that young an age it's not even an attempt at achieving orgasm usually, it's as much for comfort as sexual gratification.

Every child psychologist or expert in child development will say the same thing, even if your child was masturbating it is normal and harmless.  In fact experts agree more harm comes from parent's overreacting to a child touching themselves then to the contact itself.  Other then teaching a child such touching should be done in private, and redirecting him if he is actively doing it in a public location, it's best to just ignore it and let the kid figure things out for himself.

I see from your comment you are worried because you were molested as a child (and I'm sorry about that).  Perhaps that implies you are worried that this is a sign of molestation?  if so please don't worry, it's quite common in children and nothing bad would have had to happen to your child for him to enjoy touching himself, assuming that was even what was happening.  This is not considered an indicator of molestation or child abuse.

Just relax, there is nothing to worry about here.

Comment: I really like this answer (and agree completely), so upvoted it, but it *could really be improved/strengthened by the use of a reliable source*, especially for the statement "experts agree more harm comes from parent's overreacting to a child touching themselves then to the contact itself." Which experts? Thanks.